# String: Masking last n characters with * sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a following string:

```
99001155
```

I want to mask last 4 characters with `*` sign. For example:

> 99001155 -> 9900****

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"99001155"[0...-4] + "****"

#=> "9900****"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
str = "99001155"
str[-4..-1] = "****"
str
# => 9900****
```

Comment: Why your answer is better? Can u explain for me?

Comment: Did I ever say it was better? It is the fastest (by a very, very small margin), but it's destructive (changes the original string).

Comment: Hmm okay. I just wonder because people are voting your answer. Anyway thank you for reply. In personally I like @Brad is answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expresion, like so: 
`'99001155'.gsub(/.{4}\z/, '****')`

This has the advantage of being fairly obvious what is happening at a glance, and is easily manipulable to  only match the last four digits (for example).

Comment: You could use `sub` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
'99001155'.gsub(/\d{4}$/, '*' * 4)
```